# sequence in $L^1$ converging pointwise a.e., but not weakly.

Tags: lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Find a $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$, a $\sigma$-finite measure space and a norm-bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $L^1(X)$ that converges almost everywhere to $f$ but does not converge weakly to $f$.

Can you help me with this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the task isn't to find a sequence wich converges weakly but not strongly?

Comment: yes, I'm sure.. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes, strong convergence implies weak convergence. Also, weak convergence plus convergent norm ($\|f_n\|\to\|f\|$) implies strong convergence.

Comment: Yes. Norm convergence implies weak convergence in any normed space.

Comment: oh, sorry. I've just edited the post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Look at $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Comment: @AlexR: This is not true in $L^1$!

Answer (score 4):

*This answers the original question, wich asked for an example of strong ($L^1$) convergence instead of pointwise a.e. convergence.*

There is no such sequence because strong convergence implies weak convergence in normed spaces. For the other way around, look at $f_n(x) = \sin(nx) \to 0$ weakly, but not strongly in $L^2 [0,2\pi]$.
$$\|f_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb T)}^2 = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 nx \ \mathrm dx = \frac1n \int_0^{2\pi n} \sin^2 t \ \mathrm dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 t \ \mathrm dt = \pi < \infty$$
Note that $\pi \not\to 0 = \|0\|_{L^2(\mathbb T)}$ is the reason why it doesn't converge weakly. Weak convergence here is a consequence of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (Fourier coefficients decay)